# Is java right for this application?

Tags: java, swing, tomcat, javafx

I need a way to:

1. Create a GUI based front end to a database (MS SQL Server or MySQL).
2. I want it to be capable of running on Windows,Mac & Linux.
3. I want to be able to run the GUI as a desktop application or through a web browser.
   (some people aren't allowed to install applications on their desktops and some people                   don't have access to web browsers.)
4. I need support for rich dynamic content, graphs, tables, possibly videos.
5. A nice IDE to generate the GUI where I can visually create and then code.
6. I don't want to deal with different web browsers interpreting the layout differently.

I have programming experience but plan on hiring a professional to get this project started.  It is currently for a small business but has the potential to reach enterprise level with hundreds of users.  This is a long term project.  Some people say Java is a slow horrible language.  Some people say it is great and many enterprises and financial institutions run java.

I have done quite a bit of research on oracle's website but am still lost.

Java? Java FX? Swing? JavaEE? Tomcat? Java webstart?

Where do I even begin.  I don't even know what book to buy.  If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.  Maybe Java isn't even right for this?

Comment: This might be the wrong site for this question -- but Java sounds fine for this.

Comment: The question should not be "is Java (or whatever language)..." but "is this architecture...". And it is off topic.

Comment: It sounds like you want Java, yes. Use NetBeans with its great GUI builder. Deploying to a browser might be a bit harder, since that is done by Applets. Applets are using still AWT and modern Java applications use Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is great for just about every project. But lets address your points.

1: Java can build a GUI and it can connect to Databases there are many APIs to make this easier, like JDBC.

2: Java is build for just that. Due to Java Runtime Environment which virtualises the execution it is easy to build Java based Applications for multiple Operating Systems.

3: This one could be a bit tricky since you would build an Applet for the browser and not an Application. But hey Java is just about the only Language that allows you to build an Application and an Applet for browsers in one step. Which is also the reason for it's big success. But beware companies may block Java in browsers for security reasons.

4: Java is capable of producing every graphic you can image a great example is [Processing](http://processing.org/).

5: Well NetBeans and Eclipse both have great plugins for that. I personally love the [Window Builder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) for Eclipse.

6: An Applet will give you that because it defines it's layout. Browsers are just running the Applet and are not doing any interpretations.

As for Java being slow: Naturally since Java Applications are run in a virtual environment they are slower then Applications developed in say C++. But this allows for Java Applications to be easily released for Windows, MacOS and Linux at the same time. Also Java uses some great technics like "Adaptive optimization" to increase it's speed and today Java isn't really all that much slower than other Languages (but still slower).

You can refer to the Java-Article on Wikipedia for some more info on Java.[Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be able to run the GUI as a desktop application or through a
>   web browser. (some people aren't allowed to install applications on
>   their desktops and some people don't have  access to web browsers.)

In this case Swing might not be the best solution since running a moderately Swing app in a browser as an Applet is a pain. 
Java WebStart is a nice solution, but the application doesn't really runs in the browser: it just starts from the browser. If this is OK, than JFormDesigner http://www.jformdesigner.com/‎ is the best tool you can get.

If the application must run in the browser and without Java than you can achieve something similar with a RIA web application and package it in a similar way PhoneGap does mobile devices, e.g. with http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-webkit.html and bundle the server together in background. 
For the UI with this RIA framework http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/ there's also a very advanced GUI designer: http://www.sencha.com/products/architect/ if that's an important part, but of course in this space there are many alternatives.